# ARM doesn't properly close files, causing too many open files eventually

Tags: java, file, nio

Not sure what part of my code causes the issues exactly, but when I started pinpointing the issue, I noticed that open file count increases when I run the following code.

```
public synchronized String readStringSync(String basePath,String path){

                if(useLegacy){
                        return readStringLegacy(basePath,path);

                }
                if(!basePath.endsWith("/"))
                        basePath+="/";
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(420);
                File f= new File(basePath+path);
                if(!f.exists()){
                        return null;
                }
                Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), charset)) {
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line+"\r\n");

                        }
                        String ret = sb.toString();

                        if(ret.trim().startsWith("deleted")||ret.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("dummy"))
                                return null;
                        return ret;

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                }

        }

        public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{

                com.sun.management.UnixOperatingSystemMXBean mxb = (com.sun.management.UnixOperatingSystemMXBean)java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
                System.out.println(mxb.getOpenFileDescriptorCount());  //11

                System.out.println(readString("sometestfile"));

                Thread.sleep(1000);

                mxb = (com.sun.management.UnixOperatingSystemMXBean)java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
                System.out.println(mxb.getOpenFileDescriptorCount()); //12 wtf


        }
```

I already tried getting rid of File.exists and replacing it with Files.exists, but that did absolutely nothing.

As the stackoverflow is still complaining about the lack of details, here's the java version I am using:

java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: What is the value of `useLegacy`? Problem might be inside `readStringLegacy()`.

Comment: tried adding if(true)return null; just before the try block => file count stays at 11, so it's def about something that the try block does

Comment: Write a `for` loop with like 1000 iterations, and inside that call the same `readStringSync()` to read the same file. Print what will be the open files count after that.

Comment: tried making the wait period 10 seconds + prefacing it with System.gc(), no effect

Comment: icza, still 12 open files

Comment: tried to open 2 different files, but still getting 12 open files, wtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try-with-resources` statement properly closes the stream/reader, you should not worry about that.

If you experience that files are kept open, it is not due to a bug in your code. If you have relatively low open files system-wide, your OS or even JVM might keep them open for a while for performance reasons, and close them if this becomes an issue. From your side, you can't do more, you properly close it by using the `try-with-resources` statement.

Comment: The thing is, that the whole thing eventually starts throwing FileNotFoundException: too many open files, and that's imo def something to worry about.

Comment: The code you posted does not cause resource leak. I would look at other places in your code if I were to hunt this down.

Comment: Turns out that the main cause of leaks was indeed elsewhere. Still getting some rise in open files, but much lower and i cant get it to explode into the 4 figs anymore, so that could be due to to some optimizations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of the java.nio.parts and replaced the try line with: 
     try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(basePath+path))){

The file count stays at 11 now, but not sure if the issues that I started using java.nio for are back & not sure yet if this fixes the main issue.